# Disable option after submitting

Tags: php, html

I have a select for 2 colors.

```html
<select name="hoogte">
<? foreach ($hoogte_array as $hoogtekey => $valuehoogte) { ?>
    <option value="<?echo $hoogtekey;?>" <? if ($hoogtekey == $_SESSION['laatstehoogte']){echo "selected";}?>><?echo $valuehoogte;?></option>
<?}
```

The value stays perfecty selected and there is nothing wrong with that.

How to disable the other option after I submit?

There are 2 colors. I select one, submit the form. Value stays selected and other option is disabled.

Thanks.

Comment: you could try adding an `else isset($_SESSION['laatstehoogte']) { echo "disabled"; }` seems like bad ux to stop people from selecting the other option though - what if they chose wrong by accident?

Comment: @Pete It is not for public use but thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You put else on 'selected', if it's not selected then disabled. Also you have to check first if session is set.

```
<select name="hoogte"><?
foreach ($hoogte_array as $hoogtekey => $valuehoogte) 
    {
    ?><option value="<?= $hoogtekey;?>" <?php if(isset($_SESSION['laatstehoogte'])) { echo ($hoogtekey==$_SESSION['laatstehoogte']) ? "selected" : 'disabled'; } ?>><?= $valuehoogte;?></option><?
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

**First of all**

Your code is really bad formatted.
Instead of `<?echo` you can use `<?=`. Also short tags (`<?` instead of `<?php`) are not recommended and you should not use them.

**Secondly**

Instead of `if else` you can use short version which is really useful in situations like yours.
So instead of

```
if ($hoogtekey == $_SESSION['laatstehoogte']){echo "selected";}
```

You can write

```
echo $hoogtekey == $_SESSION['laatstehoogte'] ? "selected" : "";
```

**Thirdly**

If you use superglobal variable it is always a good thing to check if it exist and if it is not `null`. There is a function called [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php). I recommend using it. It checks both if variable does not exist or equals to `null`, `false` and so on.

**Lastly**

If you want to disable other options after select than just add `disabled` attribute to them.

Here is an example

```
<select name="hoogte">
<?php foreach ($hoogte_array as $hoogtekey => $valuehoogte) { ?>
    <option value="<?= $hoogtekey; ?>" <?= !empty($_SESSION['laatstehoogte']) && $hoogtekey == $_SESSION['laatstehoogte'] ? "selected" : "disabled"; ?>><?= $valuehoogte;?></option>
<?php }
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks! i am a beginner and this was really helpfull.